# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated For Demo Enviornment Only

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, websphere

I have two servers one is QA and another is a demo in WebSphere. for QA no error is shown but for a demo, it shows the error of javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated.

The interesting thing is the demo is the exact war copied from the QA environment. Any Ideas?

The image is attached for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G4Zr.png)

Comment: Is demo and QA pointing to the same endpoints? Just see if the certificate of the endpoint is valid or not.

Comment: I got the issue resolved. -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true added to the JVM